# Calculating the variance of an i.i.d variable

Tags: statistics, random-variables

Here is the data I have for a variable:

X = [420 450 420 380 440 380 360 360]

I'm told that X is i.i.d with mean = 390. How do I go about estimating variance? Would it simply be:

(Σ(x – xbar) ^2 )/(N)

= (Σ (Xi - 390)^2)/8

= 1237.5?

Comment: What level of a class is this? The question of estimating the variance given the *true* mean vs. using the sample mean is a bit more advanced than a typical first statistics class. I can tell you that the estimator which uses the sample mean would use $\overline{x}$, which in this case is $401.25 \neq 390$, and would divide by $N-1$ instead (so as to be unbiased). I think if the mean is actually given then the unbiased estimator would divide by $N$, but I would have to play with it to check.

Comment: This is an intermediate level class. I'm confused because the sample mean of X is 401.25, while the mean I'm given is 390.

Comment: There are different estimators for the variance. One unbiased estimator when you don't know the sample mean is $S_1^2 = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n \left ( x_i - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n x_i \right )^2$. An unbiased estimator when you actually *do* have the sample mean $\mu$ would be the usual way that you would estimate the *mean* of $(X-\mu)^2$, i.e. $S_2^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\mu)^2.$ You might check which of these estimators has higher variance to pick one. Probably the second one has lower variance (since you are "using more information" in some sense).

Comment: @Ian - I assume by "sample mean" you actually mean the population mean, right? As clearly if we have the sample, we have the sample mean ;)

Comment: @Math1000 You're right. I also have another typo: the second $x_i$ in the formula for $S_1^2$ should be $x_j$.

Answer (score 1):

**Population mean unknown.** If you are not given the population mean $\mu$, then use the formula that includes the sample mean and divides by $n - 1.$ (That's $S_1^2$ in the comment from @Ian.)

I got $\bar X = 401.25$ and $S^2 = 1269.643$.

**Population mean known.** But it seems you are given $\mu = 390.$ Then you need to use the formula that includes $\mu$ and divides by $n.$ (That's $S_2^2$ in the comment.)
For that, I got  1237.5, which agrees with the number in your question.
(However, the first and second expressions in what you wrote are *not*
equal because you have $\bar X$ in one and $\mu$ in the other.)

*In case this is an advanced course.* If the data come from a *normal* population with mean $\mu = 390,$ then the second method is
best. It will have the lower variance because it uses the true population mean rather than estimating it. If you want to make a confidence
interval for the population variance $\sigma^2$ or test a hypothesis about
the population variance, then use $n\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \mu)^2/\sigma^2 \sim CHISQ(n).$